# How to add a new value to each row in R

Tags: r, append, apply

I'm trying to add a new value to each row by using apply() and append(), for example, the original data frame like this

```
1 2 3
3 2 1
```

After adding values, it should be like this

```
1 2 3 4
3 2 1 4
```

I was trying to achieve this by apply(df, 2, append(df,4)), but it seems not work. So how to deal with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you do: `df$4 <- 4` ?

Comment: @Matt, you can't name columns in a df with numerics. you'd have to use `df$"4" <- 4`

Comment: Or `cbind(df, Y=4)` (i called the new column `Y` to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it by using cbind().

```
a<-rep(4,length.out=2)
df<-cbind(df,a)
```

If you have better ways, please just post it.